# Convert MP4 Version - FFmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp4

I have two mp4 Files:

1. `out.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]`
2. `video/rio2016/finale/brasse/200.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]`

How can I convert 1 to 2 (mp4 v1 to mp4 v2)?

Answer (score 16):

Using ffmpeg, it's

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -brand mp42 out2.mp4
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `-c copy -map 0`.

Comment: Take _all_ streams from first input (-map 0) and copy them. You only need to add `-brand mp42` to your existing command.